# OSError: [Errno 22] when I try to .read() a json file

Tags: python, json, dataset

I am simply trying to read my json file in Python. I am in the correct folder when I do so; I am in Downloads, and my file is called 'Books_5.json'. However, when I try to use the .read() function, I get the error

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

This is my code:

```
import json
config = json.loads(open('Books_5.json').read())
```

This also raises the same error:

```
books = open('Books_5.json').read()
```

If it helps, this is a small snippet of what my data looks like:

```
{"reviewerID": "A10000012B7CGYKOMPQ4L", "asin": "000100039X", "reviewerName": "Adam", "helpful": [0, 0], "reviewText": "Spiritually and mentally inspiring! A book that allows you to question your morals and will help you discover who you really are!", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Wonderful!", "unixReviewTime": 1355616000, "reviewTime": "12 16, 2012"}
{"reviewerID": "A2S166WSCFIFP5", "asin": "000100039X", "reviewerName": "adead_poet@hotmail.com \"adead_poet@hotmail.com\"", "helpful": [0, 2], "reviewText": "This is one my must have books. It is a masterpiece of spirituality. I'll be the first to admit, its literary quality isn't much. It is rather simplistically written, but the message behind it is so powerful that you have to read it. It will take you to enlightenment.", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "close to god", "unixReviewTime": 1071100800, "reviewTime": "12 11, 2003"}
```

I'm using Python 3.6 on MacOSX

Comment: Have you tried with a full path? e.g. `open(r'C:\users\your_name\Downloads\Books_5.json')`? If a full path works, but a relative path does not, your current working directory is not where you think it is.

Comment: Which version of Python? Which OS?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar let me add that info thanks for the reminder

Comment: @user45254 first of all, you have incorrect json in file. As I understood, it should be `list` - (`[{"reviewerID": ...}, {...}]`)

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks for the suggestion, yes I have tried this.

Comment: @user45254 try to use `codecs`. `import codecs
f = codecs.open(filename, encoding="utf-8") ...`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar at the .read() step, using codecs, I get the same error. Thanks for your help

Comment: hm... it's weird. Are these 2 files(json and python module) in the same directory?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Yes. Also, if the file is not found, I get a different error (file not found error).

Comment: @user45254 I don't have MacOSX and can't repeat it. Try to set empty json in file - `{}`. And check it `print(open('Books_5.json').read())`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Yes actually that works with no problem.

Comment: @user45254 so... problem with wrong content of json file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears that this is some kind of bug that occurs when the file is too large (my file was ~10GB). Once I use `split` to break up the file by 200 k lines, the `.read()` error goes away. This is true even if the file is not in strict json format.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem while opening a 8 GB json file. Could you please share how you broke up the file into 200k lines? I don't seem to get how a JSON file will be broken down into smaller files with `split`.

Comment: facing the same problem with mac version 10.13.3 and the file size is around 10GB.

Comment: alternative try loading the json as stream using [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/)

Answer (score -1):

In order to read `json` file, you can use next example:

```
with open('your_data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

print(data)
print(data[0]['your_key']) # get value via key.
```

and also try to convert your `json` objects into a list

```
[
  {'reviewerID': "A10000012B7CGYKOMPQ4L", ....},
  {'asin': '000100039X', .....}
]
```

Comment: Believe it or not, I still have the same error here: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: Maybe @DanilaGanchar is right-- if the data is in the form `{} {} {}`, not `[{},{},{}]`, is this the error that results?

Comment: Yes, you need to convert your `json` objects, into a list. And then everything should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks fine, it just looks like your json data is formatted incorrectly. Try the following. As others have suggested, it should be in the form [{},{},...].

```
[{"reviewerID": "A10000012B7CGYKOMPQ4L", "asin": "000100039X", 
"reviewerName": "Adam", "helpful": [0, 0], "reviewText": "Spiritually and 
mentally inspiring! A book that allows you to question your morals and will 
help you discover who you really are!", "overall": 5.0, "summary": 
"Wonderful!", "unixReviewTime": 1355616000, "reviewTime": "12 16, 2012"},
{"reviewerID": "A2S166WSCFIFP5", "asin": "000100039X", "reviewerName": 
"adead_poet@hotmail.com \"adead_poet@hotmail.com\"", "helpful": [0, 2], 
"reviewText": "This is one my must have books. It is a masterpiece of 
spirituality. I'll be the first to admit, its literary quality isn't much. 
It is rather simplistically written, but the message behind it is so 
powerful that you have to read it. It will take you to enlightenment.", 
"overall": 5.0, "summary": "close to god", "unixReviewTime": 1071100800, 
"reviewTime": "12 11, 2003"}]
```

Your code and this data worked for me on Windows 7 and python 2.7. Different than your setup, but should still be ok.

Comment: Yes that does work. Do you happen to have any quick ways of converting the data? It is a very large file. I was thinking of inserting a comma following every `}`, except the last one, and then adding [ at the beginning and ] at the end. What is the pythonic way, if it is off the top of your head? Otherwise I will just figure it out . Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are they all on separate lines like in your example? If they are, just read the file one line at a time (see [`readline()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html))  and append each line to a list.

Comment: I think so, I'll test later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: that did not work either. But it turns out the problem was that the file was too large. See my answer below

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable