# Python read file limitations on macOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io, macos-sierra

I've read some topics (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723468/oserror-errno-22-when-i-try-to-read-a-json-file)) regarding this issue, but it was a side issue and only workarounds were proposed/accepted as an solution.

So is there a way to fix the issue as is, without "read by chunks in a loop":

```
with open(fileName, 'rb') as bytestream:
     buf = bytestream.read()
```

When file is larger then ~2GB (presumably signed int32) it produces this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

My config:

> Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25)
>   [GCC 4.2.1
>   (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
>   OS: macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 (16G1212)

Comment: is your python version a 64bit version?

Comment: Bad news, this bug is still an open issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre according to this test it's 64 bit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os

Comment: seems like macos is trusted by architects & lawyers who don't care about python being fixed :)

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard thanks. This seems awkward for me.  Python is so unpopular thing that such a common bug in major IO module hasn't been resolved for two years?